# matching result from array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How to match value/text `Trykk` front when the result from var_dump($haystack) looks like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(11) {
        ["id"] => string(13) "64085aafcb9db"
        ["type"] => string(10) "checkboxes"
        ["raw"] => array(1) {
            [2] => string(5) "b3ygo"
        }
        ["values"] => array(1) {
            [0] => array(6) {
                ["label"] => string(11) "Trykk front"
                ["price"] => float(42)
                ["price_type"] => string(2) "qt"
                ["slug"] => string(5) "b3ygo"
                ["calc_price"] => float(42)
                ["pricing_hint"] => string(23) "(+kr 42)"
            }
        }
        ["clone_type"] => string(0) ""
        ["label"] => string(31) "Ønsker du trykk på produktet?"
        ["hide_cart"] => bool(false)
        ["hide_checkout"] => bool(false)
        ["hide_order"] => bool(false)
        ["clone_idx"] => int(0)
        ["calc_weight"] => bool(false)
    }
    [1] => array(11) {
        ["id"] => string(13) "64085aaf29908"
        ["type"] => string(4) "file"
        ["raw"] => string(0) ""
        ["values"] => array(1) {
            [0]=>array(4) {
                ["label"] => string(0) ""
                ["price"] => int(0)
                ["price_type"] => string(4) "none"
                ["formatted_label"]=>string(31) ""
            }
        }
        ["clone_type"] => string(0) ""
        ["label"] => string(56) "Om du ønsker trykk på produktet laster du opp logo her"
        ["hide_cart"] => bool(false)
        ["hide_checkout"] => bool(false)
        ["hide_order"] => bool(false)
        ["clone_idx"] => int(0)
        ["calc_weight"] => bool(false)
    }
}
```

```
$matches  = preg_grep ('/^Trykk front (\w+)/i', $haystack);
```

Comment: `preg_grep()` expects an array of strings, not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: And this appears to be multi-dimensional. `Trykk front` is in `$haystack[0]['values'][0]['label']`. You need nested loops.

Comment: @Barmar was working for me! if ($haystack[0]['values'][0]['label'] ==='Trykk front'){
  
 echo "Result is Match" ; }

Comment: What is your exact desired result from your sample data?  Might your sought value occur more than once?  How does that affect the desired result?  Are you merely checking if the value exists or do you actually need to access data upon finding the match?  Your question is lacking details.  Accessing multidimensional array data is a topic that is well covered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like:

```
print_r(array_filter($array, function($a){
    return $a['values'][0]['label'] === 'Trykk front';
}));
```

[Fiddle](https://onlinephp.io/c/0d309)

Comment: If the answer is "use array_filter() to conditionally exclude data", we already have duplicates for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `var_dump` output, "Trykk front" is from `$haystack[0]['values']`. So, assuming your code needs to be updated like this:

```php
$values = $haystack[0]['values'];

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $label = $value['label'];

    if (preg_match('/^Trykk front/i', $label)) {
        // Match found
        echo "Match found: " . $label;
        break;
    }
}
```